# cancancan polymorphic associations ability (has_many)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, authorization, cancancan, has-many-polymorphs

i have nested resources and i want to allow departments/1/lists, companies/1/lists and goes on, how can i do that? Btw, Im using rails 5 and cancancan 2.0

Here is my files:

routes.rb

```
resources :departments do
    resources :lists
  end

  resources :lists do
    member do
      put :done
    end
  end

  devise_for :users, :skip => [:registrations]

  devise_scope :user do
    root to: "devise/sessions#new"
    get "/users/edit" => "devise/registrations#edit", :as => :edit_user_registration
    patch "/users" => "devise/registrations#update", :as => :user_registration
    put "/users" => "devise/registrations#update"
  end

  resources :users do
    resources :lists
  end

  resources :companies do
    resources :lists
  end
```

list.rb

```
class List < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :listable, polymorphic: true
    end
```

department.rb

```
class Department < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lists,  as: :listable
end
```

company.rb

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord  
  has_many :lists, as: :listable
end
```

lists_controller.rb

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
  load_resource :department
  load_resource :company
  load_resource :user
  load_and_authorize_resource :list, :through => [:department, :company, :user]
```

ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new

    if user.has_role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, List, { :company => { :id => user.company_id } }
      can :read, List, { :department => { :id => user.departments.first.id } }
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks.

I still can not figure it out

Somebody please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
  load_resource :department
  load_resource :company
  load_resource :user
  load_and_authorize_resource :list, :through => [:department, :company, :user]
end
```

Not `lists`, it would be `list` :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After I did what you said, I got an error like this.

`
NoMethodError in ListsController#index
undefined method 'klass’ for nil:NilClass

         if value.is_a? Hash
            value = value.dup
            association_class = model_class.reflect_on_association(name).klass.name.constantize
            nested_resulted = value.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), nested|
              if v.is_a? Hash
                value.delete(k)
`

Can you help me with this?

Comment: could you please provide the code of `index` action?

Comment: I fixed the question, would you look again?